# How to capture queries run by a specific user in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Messed with SQL Sentry, I guess it could be done with a trace as well. Any recommended ways to watch/log the queries of a particular user? Logging it anytime they run it. i.e. if they ran it at night?

Comment: SQL Profiler and filter by user / login?

Comment: Any way to log any query they ran?

Comment: Sql Profiler, filter by user / login. Profiler can absolutly profile queries.

Comment: Gah, sorry wasn't what I meant to write. Any way to log 'every' query they ran

Answer (score 2):

Try to use SQL Server system functions: Execution Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188068.aspx

For example:

- 1. Get SessionID by user:

  `exec sp_who;`
- 2. Use this:

  `select a.session_id, st.text as QueryText from sys.dm_exec_connections a CROSS APPLY sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(a.most_recent_sql_handle) st  where a.session_id = SessionID;`